# Sharing MenuStrip between Forms

Tags: c#, menustrip

I have a question a litle bit connected with this one: [How to create navigation inside program Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549959/how-to-create-navigation-inside-program-form) - noob alert again.

I'm trying to create a navigation inside c# program like a dynamic dropdown menu on website. I'm using diferent C# Forms like each and every one one was a different webpage with content.

Is is posible to share menustrip with navigation between Forms? (simplest web similarity: include('menu.php') - put everything into one file I inlcude on every webpage )

Otherwise it would require to copy menustrip to each new Form (then MenuStrip changes, and then what? Copy them again ? :) )

Comment: you have "window forms" that each has a "webpage" inside ? why are you doing ti like that ?

Comment: I dont have a webpage inside :) I'm a webdeveloper trying to learn c# - so I use similarities to describe what I want to do. And wat I want do to is to create inside program navigation in bigger c# program.

Comment: MDI looks interesting - I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via joining tabs with Srip Meni like this:

```
//make tabs invisible (so you wont see them changing)
private void HideAllTabsOnTabControl(TabControl theTabControl)
{
    theTabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
    theTabControl.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
    theTabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
}

//hide all tabs
private void hide_all_tabs() {
    Tab_content.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1);
    Tab_content.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2);
    Tab_content.TabPages.Remove(tabPage3);
    Tab_content.TabPages.Remove(tabPage4);
}
private void materiałyQCToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hide_all_tabs(); //hide everything
    Tab_content.TabPages.Add(tabPage1); //schow just first tab
}
private void analizatoryQCToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hide_all_tabs();
    Tab_content.TabPages.Add(tabPage2);
}
private void QCzDzisiajToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hide_all_tabs();
    Tab_content.TabPages.Add(tabPage3);
}
private void standlabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hide_all_tabs();
    Tab_content.TabPages.Add(tabPage4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance, if you want to share items between a ContextMenu and the main Form MenuStrip

[image: No items defined]

MenuStrip without items

[image]

ContextMenu items

[image]

ContextMenu with copied items from ContextMenu

On main Form you can do:

```
ToolStripMenuItem toolStripMoved;
ToolStripItem[] itemsArrayMoved;

private void Edit_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = DockPanel.GetDocuments().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Visible) as DockDocument;
    if (doc != null)
    {
        toolStripMoved = doc.ContextMenuStrip.Items["Edit"] as ToolStripMenuItem;
        if (toolStripMoved != null)
        {
            var menu = (sender as ToolStripMenuItem);
            itemsArrayMoved = Helper.GetAllChildren(toolStripMoved);
            foreach (ToolStripItem item in itemsArrayMoved)
            {
                if (item.Name.Equals("Edit") == false)
                    menu.DropDownItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Edit_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripMoved != null)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripItem item in itemsArrayMoved)
        {
            if (item.Name.Equals("Edit") == false)
                toolStripMoved.DropDownItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

static private ToolStripItem[] GetAllChildren(ToolStripItem item)
{
    List<ToolStripItem> Items = new List<ToolStripItem>() { item };
    if (item is ToolStripMenuItem)
        foreach (ToolStripItem i in ((ToolStripMenuItem)item).DropDownItems)
            Items.AddRange(GetAllChildren(i));
    else if (item is ToolStripSplitButton)
        foreach (ToolStripItem i in ((ToolStripSplitButton)item).DropDownItems)
            Items.AddRange(GetAllChildren(i));
    else if (item is ToolStripDropDownButton)
        foreach (ToolStripItem i in ((ToolStripDropDownButton)item).DropDownItems)
            Items.AddRange(GetAllChildren(i));
    return Items.ToArray();
}
```